# Spring security xml configruation not working

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, xml-configuration

I have the problem spring security. I am implementing spring security using xml configruation. I have create the project in the following.

[image]

it is spring mvc project using maven architecture. First, I have integrate myabtis and the project still run properly. However, when I start implement spring security it turn error 404 every time.

You can have a look at my xml configuration below.

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="kh.com.ibs.qms.*.common.*" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="kh.com.ibs.qms.*.business.*" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
        </property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/qmsdb">
        </property>
        <property name="username" value="qmsadmin"></property>
        <property name="password" value="ibs2016"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="SpirytusLogoutSuccessHandler"
        class="jp.co.gfam.spirytus.common.security.SpirytusLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <property name="useReferer" value="true" />
    </bean> -->

    <!-- Transaction definition -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"
                isolation="DEFAULT" timeout="600" read-only="false"
                rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <!-- Transaction Management -->
<!--     <aop:config>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice"
            pointcut="execution(kh.com.ibs.qms.*.business.service.*Service.*(..))" />
    </aop:config> -->

    <!-- Message Setting -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
             class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>i18n/message</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="rsj23.rhostjh.com" />
        <property name="protocol" value="smtp" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="noreply.daruma@gfam-kh.com" />
        <property name="password" value="Cos7gEv0yOz0" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">rsj23.rhostjh.com</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="velocityEngine"
        class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
            <value>
                resource.loader=class
                class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

applicationContext-securities.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- ************************************************************ Spring 
        Security for Filter URL pattern specified to the outside of the object of 
        processing************************************************************ -->
    <sec:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
    <sec:http pattern="**/resources/**" security="none" />
    <sec:http pattern="/login" security="none" />

    <!-- ************************************************************ Spring 
        Security basic setting ************************************************************ -->
    <sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <!-- URL controlled by security -->
        <!-- Specify the URL if need restriction -->
        <!-- <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" /> -->
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <!-- Loin setting -->
        <sec:form-login username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/login/auth" default-target-url="/home"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </sec:http>


    <!-- ************************************************************ Spring 
        Security's authentication setting *********************************************************** -->
    <sec:authentication-manager>
        <!-- <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"> 
            <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" /> </sec:authentication-provider> -->
        <sec:authentication-provider ref='daoAuthenticationProvider' />
    </sec:authentication-manager>
<sec:debug/>
    <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false" />
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="kh.com.ibs.qms.common.security.AuthenticationUserService">
    </bean>
    <!-- Pasword encoding -->
    <bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder" />
    <bean id="CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="kh.com.ibs.qms.common.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="csrfSecurityRequestMatcher" class="kh.com.ibs.qmatic.common.security.CsrfSecurityRequestMatcher"> 
        </bean> -->
</beans>
```

applicationContext-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="kh.com.ibs.qms.*.presentation.controller" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/content/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:email.properties" />

</beans>
```

applicationContext-mybatis.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mybatis="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring
        http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis.xml" />
        <property name="mapperLocations"
            value="classpath*:mapper/*-mapper.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="kh.com.ibs.qms.*.dataaccess.dao" />
        <property name="annotationClass"
            value="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml,classpath:applicationContext-web.xml,classpath:applicationContext-mybatis.xml,classpath:applicationContext-securities.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>





    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>      
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>kh.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibs</artifactId>
    <name>test</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<
```

/project>

when i run the application it simple turn to error 404 and there is no error message too. So please help. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Please help me. You see the source code of the project with this link  [source code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=29789947B9C4F38B!371865&authkey=!AIoTyEDLkrsmdpk&ithint=file%2Crar)

Comment: Is the application coming up fine? Did you notice any error when the server comes up or webapp getting started?

Comment: No I see the log on server there's no error but the page displays error 404. U can check the project sources code I put in the link. It is eclipse project

Comment: @minion did you check it yet?

Comment: @minion what's up man?